What are the equivalence classes for the set of pairs $(\mathbf{x},U)$, where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U$ is a one-dimensional subspace?
I am trying to develop $\pi$ in the following classification by representatives discussed in Janich, Linear Algebra (1994), pg. 174.

In my first attempt, I came up with the following transformations for each one of the representatives. They are:
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi_{0}(\mathbf{x})  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  \\
\varphi_{1}(\mathbf{x}) =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta_{1}) & -\sin(\theta_{1}) \\
\sin(\theta_{1}) &  \cos(\theta_{1})  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{x} \| } & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{x} \| }
\end{bmatrix}\\
\varphi_{2}(\mathbf{x}) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta_{2}) & -\sin(\theta_{2}) \\
\sin(\theta_{2}) &  \cos(\theta_{2})  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\| \mathbf{x} \| } & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{x} \| }
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
where $\theta_1$ is the angle of $\mathbf{x}$ with the x-axis and $\theta_2$ with the y-axis.
However, they are not automorphisms. Could you tell me which transformations Janich had in mind in the above problem?

Clarification:
I misunderstood the problem. Here is the idea after the accepted answer. First, you need to focus on the elements of $M$ not on the functions $\varphi$. For instance, it is possible that the same function $\varphi$ sends $(0,U)\to(0,\mathbb{R} \times 0)$ and $(x \in U \backslash \{0\},U)\to ((1,0),\mathbb{R}\times 0)$ but we are not interested in decompose the space of functions $\varphi$ but the set $M$. Instead, we should see where the elements go as we apply the functions $\varphi$. After a while, you may see that if we start in an element $(x,U)$ we can visit just a set of elements $G \subset M$. Those new subsets will create islands that cannot be visited by any other element outside $G$. I drew a picture to express this idea.


I can't discern what you're saying.  What is $\varphi_0$?  It looks like you might be saying $\varphi_0(\mathbf{x})$ is the automorphism, but since it's not injective, it cannot be.

Uow, I see. So what are they?

I don't understand who is "they" in your "what are they"?

I did a clarification in the post. I started with the wrong idea from the beginning.

The automorphisms of $\Bbb R^2$ to be considered here are the automorphisms of vector space, i.e. the bijective linear maps $\varphi:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,\;\mathbf x\mapsto A\mathbf x$ where $A$ is some fixed invertible matrix (independent of $\mathbf x$).
For every $(x,U),(y,V)\in M$:

if an automorphism maps $U$ to $V$ and $x$ to $y$ then:

$x=0\iff y=0$,
$x\in U\iff y\in V$.


Conversely, there exist infinitely many automorphisms mapping $U$ to $V$, and:

they all map $0$ to $0$,
if $x\in U\setminus\{0\}$ and $y\in V\setminus\{0\}$, still infinitely many of these automorphisms map $x$ to $y$,
if $x\notin U$ and $y\notin V$, exactly one of these automorphisms maps $x$ to $y$.



Therefore, there are three equivalence classes:
$$\begin{cases}\{(x,U)\in M\mid x=0\}\\\{(x,U)\in M\mid x\in U\setminus\{0\}\}\\\{(x,U)\in M\mid x\notin U\}.\end{cases}$$

Thanks! Could you provide example for each one of them? I am not seeing that they are mutually exclusive.

I am not sure what you mean by "they are mutually exclusive".  These 3 subsets are clearly disjoint. The fact that any two equivalent elements of $M$ must be in the same subset is proved in the 1st part (i.e. before "Conversely"). Not sure either what kind of examples you want. Aren't those from Janich sufficient?

Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism that sends $(0,U) \rightarrow (0, \mathbb{R} \times 0)$. It could be possible that $\varphi$ also sends $(x \in U,U) \rightarrow ((1,0), \mathbb{R} \times 0)$?

Your question is not completely clear to me but seems to be equivalent to: "Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism, and $U:=\varphi^{-1}(\Bbb R\times0)$. Does $x:=\varphi^{-1}((1,0))$ belong to $U$?" The answer is obviously yes.

Ok, many thanks!

Now, I am little bit curious. We have found a relation between an infinite space $M$ and a discrete set with 3 elements. Is this a deep result? Say, It reveals some hidden structure of linear spaces, appears in other branches of math and extend to higher dimensions?

That "relation" is that the small one is a quotient of the big one by some equivalence relation. Or equivalently: it is the image of the big one under some map. This is extremely frequent, in all branches of math.
